# Getting progress information/make a progress bar from file upload in .NET 5 Blazor PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am uploading multiple files in my (.Net5) Blazor WebAssembly app.
I have a 'ObjectDTO' That contains info and a list of file objects like this:

```
        public class ObjectDTO
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }


            public string Name { get; set; }


            public string Description { get; set; }

            public decimal ActualCost { get; set; }   // Not sent to app.

            public decimal NormalRetailPrice { get; set; }

            public string StatusMsg { get; set; }

            public ICollection<ExternalFileDTO> ImageFiles { get; set; } // Videos/Images 

        }
```

The 'Icollection' is the object that contains the files and looks like this:

```
        public class ExternalFileDTO
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string CreatedById { get; set; }  // All images have a user - at least who uploaded it.

            public DateTimeOffset? CreatedDate { get; set; }   

            public string FileExtension { get; set; }

            public string Title { get; set; }

            public string Text { get; set; }

            public string ExternalUrl { get; set; }

            public string LocalFileName { get; set; }

            public string FileType { get; set; }

            //Only in the DTO
            public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
        }
```

I have a service that sends an updated 'Object' to the server:

```
            public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateObject(ObjectDTO object)
            {
                return await Http.PostAsJsonAsync(Routes.UpdateObjectRoute, object);
            }
```

Since there is a chance this could be quite large, I would like to be able to show the user a progress bar. Is there a 'simple' way of getting progress information in the PostAsJsonAsync function or am I approaching this badly... I have seen examples where single files are uploaded, but I would have preferred to keep the data all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by taking a different approach and uploading directly to azure from the client in all cases. I put this out there to try and help anyone else with the same issues.

To do this I created server api calls to handle an 'ExternalFileDTO' object that I can passs back and forth.
The server is called to get an upload SAS key, provide an upload URI and in the process creates a DB record.

The file(s) are uploaded directly to azure, and then for each one, the server is called again to verify completion.

I am really grateful to Andrew Hoefling's blog here: [Upload Large Files in C#](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/uploading-large-files-to-azure-blob-storage-in-c-sharp)

Also, trawling through the docs, i figured out how to set up iProgress Handlers.

Here's the code:

```
       public long maxFileSize = 2000000000;
    const int BufferSize = 1000000;
    const int maxAllowedFiles = 5;
    //string AllowedFileTypes = String.Join(",", Permitted.Extensions);
    public string AllowedFileTypes = string.Join(",", FileExtensions.ValidExtensionsAll);

    public async Task<InfoBool> HandleFilesUpload(FileChangedEventArgs e, IProgress<Tuple<int, int, string>> progressHandler,
        IProgress<Tuple<int,string>> fileCountHandler, ExternalFileDTO fileTemplate, InfoBool isCancelling)
    {

        int FileCount =0;
        fileTemplate.CreatedBy = _userservice.CurrentUser;
        Tuple<int, string> reportfile;
        Tuple<int, int, string> CountProgressName;
        foreach (var file in e.Files)
        {
            FileCount++;
            reportfile = Tuple.Create(FileCount, file.Name);

            fileCountHandler.Report(reportfile);
            try
            {
                if (file == null)
                {
                    return new InfoBool(false, "File is null");

                }
                long filesize = file.Size;
                if (filesize > maxFileSize)
                {
                    return new InfoBool(false, "File exceeds Max Size");

                }
                fileTemplate.OriginalFileName = file.Name;

                var sendfile = await _azureservice.GetAzureUploadURLFile(fileTemplate);
                if (!sendfile.Status.Success) // There was an error so return the details
                {
                    return sendfile.Status;
                }
                CurrentFiles.Add(sendfile); // Add the returned sendfile object to the list
                BlockBlobClient blockBlobclient = new BlockBlobClient(sendfile.CloudURI);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize), BufferSize))
                {
                    int readCount = 0;
                    int bytesRead;
                    long TotalBytesSent = 0;
                    // track the current block number as the code iterates through the file
                    int blockNumber = 0;

                    // Create list to track blockIds, it will be needed after the loop
                    List<string> blockList = new List<string>();

                    while ((bytesRead = await bufferedStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BufferSize)) > 0)
                    {
                        blockNumber++;
                        // set block ID as a string and convert it to Base64 which is the required format
                        string blockId = $"{blockNumber:0000000}";
                        string base64BlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId));

                        Console.WriteLine($"Read:{readCount++} {bytesRead / (double)BufferSize} MB");

                        // Do work on the block of data
                        await blockBlobclient.StageBlockAsync(base64BlockId, new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                        // add the current blockId into our list
                        blockList.Add(base64BlockId);
                        TotalBytesSent += bytesRead;
                        int PercentageSent = (int)(TotalBytesSent * 100 / filesize);
                        CountProgressName = Tuple.Create(FileCount, PercentageSent, file.Name);
                        if (isCancelling.Success) //Used an InfoBool so its passed by reference
                        {
                            break; // The user has cancelled, so wind up.
                        }
                        progressHandler.Report(CountProgressName);
                    }
                    // add the blockList to the Azure which allows the resource to stick together the chunks
                    if (isCancelling.Success)
                    {
                        await blockBlobclient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(); // Delete the blob created
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await blockBlobclient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockList);
                    }
                    // make sure to dispose the stream once your are done
                    bufferedStream.Dispose();   // Belt and braces
                }
                //
                // Now make a server API call to verify the file upload was successful
                //
                // Set the file status to the cancelling, cos the server can delete the file.
                sendfile.Status = isCancelling;
                await _azureservice.VerifyFileAsync(sendfile);

                if (isCancelling.Success)
                {
                    break;      // This breaks out of the foreach loop
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
        return new InfoBool(true, "All Ok");

    }
```

... and heres the code from the Blazor UI thread page:

```
        public InfoBool IsCancelling = new InfoBool(false, "Not Cancelling"); // To allow cancel of upload

        protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        progressHandler = new Progress<Tuple<int, int, string>>(UploadProgressChanged);
        fileCountHandler = new Progress<Tuple<int,string>>(FileCountChanged);
        FileService.CurrentFilesChanged += Refresh; // Refresh the page on the change of files
    }

    private void FileCountChanged(Tuple<int,string> FileNoAndNameSending)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"FileCount Changed  = {FileNoAndNameSending}");
        FileCount = FileNoAndNameSending.Item1;
        FileNameUploading = FileNoAndNameSending.Item2;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void UploadProgressChanged(Tuple<int, int, string> CountProgressName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File Name: {CountProgressName.Item3} /n Fileno: {CountProgressName.Item1}, Upload Progress Changed Percentage = {CountProgressName.Item2}");
        FileCount = CountProgressName.Item1;
        ProgressPercent = CountProgressName.Item2;
        FileNameUploading = CountProgressName.Item3;
        if (FileCount >= TotalFilesUploading && ProgressPercent >=100)
        {
            // This is the last file and it is complete
            Console.WriteLine($"Last File reached at 100%");
            IsUploading = false;
            // UploadingComplete = true; // Set the finished flag
            HideModal();    //File has finished uploading close and refresh
            OnUserFilesUploaded.InvokeAsync();
        }
        // ShowStatusMsg($"Uploading no {FileCount} - {FileNameUploading} -{ProgressPercent}% Complete");
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
```

I am in progress sortin out the 'isCancelling' at the moment, but it does get passed to the main loop and cancels it. I am having trouble deleting the blockBlob (another question on this site).

Anyway, good luck with getting working...  this does.

**EDIT** The service gets a write SAS key to the Blob storage:

```
    //Returns the URI to use to upload the file or null/empty.
    public async Task<SASKeyDTO> GetAzureUploadURL(string FileName)
    {
        SASKeyDTO filekeyinfo = new SASKeyDTO();
        SASKeyDTO result;
        filekeyinfo.Id = _userservice.CurrentUser.Id;
        filekeyinfo.FileName = FileName;
        filekeyinfo.Text = "Azure Upload Test File";
        filekeyinfo.Title = "Test File";


        try
        {
            var response = await HttpPrivate.PostAsJsonAsync<SASKeyDTO>(Routes.GetWriteSASKeyRoute, filekeyinfo);

            result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<SASKeyDTO>();
            string url = result.BlobUri.ToString();
            return result;
        }
        catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
        {
            exception.Redirect();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This protects the client from having to have the credentials by getting a SAS key from the server.

Comment: Doesn't direct upload to Azure from WASM mean that your credentials are unprotected?

Comment: Hi @JamesMcCormack, No it doesnt, because I get a write URL SAS key from the server. There is no time the credentials get near the client. I guess if anything, there is a short term loophole getting the Write URL, but that is seriously going to tale some doing.

Comment: I have put the  client code for the service in as an edit. If you need the server end shoult up and I'll add that too. :)